# Search in a list and replace from a list but with exact match

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Sheet1 A1:A I have a list of words. In Sheet2 A1:A I have a list with search terms. I now want to match each cell in Sheet1 to see if it contains words from the list of search terms. If yes, then the the words that matches inside the cell should be removed.
I have tried the following formulas, unfortunately without success.

```
=ArrayFormula(regexreplace(A1:A;Sheet2!A:A;""))
=substitute(A1;Sheet2!A$1:A;"")
```

The formula mentioned in the post [Using multiple SUBSTITUTE functions dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67225450/using-multiple-substitute-functions-dynamically) does not working for me because I need an exact match regexreplace.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A), REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B),),))
```

This will also remove the words from words that are part of words. for example, not only the word apple will be deleted, but also the word apple from appletree, which is not supposed to be.

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**plain text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to the question. Adding such "markdown tables" greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Remember always to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A), REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\b("&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B)&")\b",),))
```

and see if that helps?